# How can I access array when I put it in this.state?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

[image]I am new to react and have read the react docs on how to make an Ajax call. They made it look so simple when they were returning the json information but it doesn't work for me. I am trying to call the json information and set it to this.state.stockSymbol but every time I try to access the information I use typeof and it returns an object. I can see the json information clearly when I console.log it but for some reason it won't update in my getSymbol function. I think it has to to with the async call but I'm not totally understanding it. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Here is my code:

```
class Stocks extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            userInput: '',
            stockSymbol: [],
            isLoaded: false
        }
    }

    typeSymbol = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            userInput: e.target.value.toUpperCase()
        }, (e) => {
            console.log(this.state.userInput)
        })
    }

    getSymbol = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault(),
            this.setState({
                stockSymbol: this.state.stockSymbol
            }, () => {
                console.log(typeof this.state.stockSymbol)
                console.log(this.state.stockSymbol)
            })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/symbol?exchange=US&token=${key}`)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(
                (results) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        stockSymbol: results
                    });
                    console.log(results)
                },
                (error) => {
                    this.setState({
                        isLoaded: true,
                        error
                    });
                }
            )
    }


    render() {
        const { stockSymbol, userInput, results } = this.state


        stockSymbol.map((stock, i) => {

            if (userInput === this.state.stockSymbol) {
                return (
                    console.log('same'),
                    <span className="symbol" key={i} onSubmit={this.getSymbol}>
                        {stock.displaySymbol}
                    </span>
                );
            }
        })



        return (
            <div className="enterstock">
                <h1 className="title">Enter Stock Symbol</h1>
                <span className="symbol">{this.state.userInput}</span>
                <form className="inputfields" onSubmit={this.getSymbol}>
                    <input type="text" className="symfields" name="symbolname" onChange={this.typeSymbol}></input>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn">Send</button>
                </form>
            </div >
        )

    }
}




ReactDOM.render(
    <Stocks />,
    document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217804/discussion-on-question-by-alanaj-how-can-i-access-array-when-i-put-it-in-this-st).

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of issues but not with fetching data.

1. What you are trying to do is filter stock symbols but you are comparing userInput with Stock symbol rather than with name of each stock
2. getSymbol doesn't need to setState as you already have set the state after fetching data.

Here is a sandbox that you can try out which does exactly what you are looking for: https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-dream-jwe7g?file=/src/index.js
Search "leanne graham" to test out

Comment: @ Ravi Chaudhary, isn't the jsx already outside the map function

Comment: I used this and it still didn't render. I'm still looking into it

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the problem is with your render function, the mapped isn't actually being rendered. You have to return a single jsx expression that contains everything.

```
    render() {
        const { stockSymbol, userInput, results } = this.state


        const symbols = stockSymbol.map((stock, i) => {
            // removed your if statement, it didn't make sense
            return (
              <span className="symbol" key={i} onSubmit={this.getSymbol}>
                 {stock.displaySymbol}
              </span>
            );
        })

        return (
          <>
            {symbols}
            <div className="enterstock">
                <h1 className="title">Enter Stock Symbol</h1>
                <span className="symbol">{this.state.userInput}</span>
                <form className="inputfields" onSubmit={this.getSymbol}>
                    <input type="text" className="symfields" name="symbolname" onChange={this.typeSymbol}></input>
                    <button type="submit" className="btn">Send</button>
                </form>
            </div >
          </>
        )

    }
```

Comment: I'd also strongly suggest looking into React hooks and functional components. A component like this would be dramatically simpler if coded that way.

Comment: I'm new to react so I'm just trying to figure things out. If this is confusing me, hooks won't be any better.

Comment: I'd argue that hooks are much easier to understand than class components.

Comment: @ murrayju That sounds good, thanks for the info but I want to learn everything so I can be more well rounded developer.

Comment: If I use your code the list of stock symbols render to the page. I want the user to type in the info to get the stock they typed in